# Newsletter - BBC and unsubscribe link

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, swiftmailer

Newsletter Table:

```
id | email | unsubscribe_link

$emails = NewsletterTable::getInstance()->findAll();    
$count = count($emails);
$message = $this->getMailer()->compose();
    $message->setSubject($params['subject']);
    $message->setTo($params['to']));
    $message->setFrom($params['from']);

for($i=1;$i<$count;$i++){
 $message->addBcc($emails[$i]->email);
}


$html = $this->getPartial('mymodule/myTemplateHtml',$params);
$message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
$text = $this->getPartial('mymodule/myTemplateTxt',$params);
$message->addPart($text, 'text/plain');    

$this->getMailer()->send($message);
```

What i must add for this that send also unsubscribe_link (unique)?  Is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're using Doctrine. I'm not an expert in how to do this with doctrine, but as as hack you could do this:

```
$emails = NewsletterTable::getInstance()->findAll();    
$count = count($emails);
$message = $this->getMailer()->compose();
    $message->setSubject($params['subject']);
    $message->setTo($params['to']));
    $message->setFrom($params['from']);

$bccEmails = array();
for($i=1;$i<$count;$i++){
    $bccEmails[$emails[$i]] = true;
}
foreach ($bccEmails as $emailAddr => $dummy) {
    $message->addBcc($emailAddr);
}
```

The idea here would be to create a dictionary of email addresses, and duplicates wouldn't affect it since dictionaries can't have duplicate entries. Then, loop through the keys of the dictionary and add them.

Comment: i would like send specify email with unique unsibscribe_link for other user